# Why does include() call PublicStream::stream_set_option()?

Tags: stream-wrappers

I am including a PHP file that in stored in the public:// directory.

(Yes, I know that's generally a bad thing, but there are reasons, and this is done on a local development server.)

I get this warning.

> User warning: stream_set_option() not supported for local file based stream wrappers in Drupal\Core\StreamWrapper\LocalStream->stream_set_option() (line 356 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/StreamWrapper/LocalStream.php).

I don't understand what's going on.

Why is `include()` calling `PublicStream::stream_set_option()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens with PHP 7.4, where one of the [backward incompatible changes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.incompatible.php) is the following one.

> When using include/require on a stream, [`streamWrapper::stream_set_option()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/streamwrapper.stream-set-option.php) will be invoked with the `STREAM_OPTION_READ_BUFFER` option. Custom stream wrapper implementations may need to implement the `streamWrapper::stream_set_option()` method to avoid a warning (always returning `FALSE` is a sufficient implementation).

Even with the latest code committed in Drupal 9, [`LocalStream::stream_set_option()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21StreamWrapper%21LocalStream.php/function/LocalStream%3A%3Astream_set_option/9.0.x) triggers the user error you are seeing.

```php
public function stream_set_option($option, $arg1, $arg2) {
  trigger_error('stream_set_option() not supported for local file based stream wrappers', E_USER_WARNING);
  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: So in my case, I need to get from settings the path that public:// represents, and *then* use include on that.

Comment: Directly using the path of the file to include would avoid that user error. I would rather do so, especially because the public:// directory doesn't usually change very often.

Comment: I understand that using public:// would make the code work for every site, without editing the code to correct the file path. I also doubt Drupal core maintainers will remove the code triggering the user error to allow users to use `include()` with public://.

Comment: I've fixed it by doing: ```$directory = str_replace("public://", \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath("public://") . '/', $directory);```
and so it still works on every site.

Comment: @joachim You could also use `$instance = \Drupal::service('stream_wrapper_manager')->getViaScheme('public'); if ($instance) { $path = $instance->realpath() . '/' . $directory }` (where `$directory` would be the path without public://).

Comment: A more generic code would resolve the path without assuming the path starts necessarily with public://.

Comment: Actually, it's enough to use `$directory = \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath($uri);` where `$uri` is for example `'public://subdirectory/file`'. The code would work even if `$uri` is, for example, `'private://subdirectory/file'`.

Comment: The path I have is stored in config, and comes with 'public://' prefixed for the benefit of other code that opens the file rather than includes it. It's the classes here if you're interested - https://github.com/drupal-code-builder/drupal-code-builder/tree/3.3.x/Storage